# Excel- How to only copy and paste a "specific" string value from one column to another column?

Tags: string, excel, copy, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am quite new to Excel and these past few days I acquired some basic skills with coding matrix formulas.
Unfortunately, I have not gained the skills yet to easily tweak formulas. I tried a couple of things but I always get an error message saying the formula does not exist or has too many actions.

I have a column A containing the string values "medication A" and "medication B" and "0" if there is no medication used. Next to this, I created a new column B where I only want to have the string value "medication A" in it.

In the first cell of column B I tried writing a code like:

=IF(A1="* Medication A *";=A1;0)

But unfortunately, this code does not exist.

Is there a code who ignores "Medication B" but puts the string value/whole word "Medication A" in my new column?

Thanks in advance!

You'd be a total lifesaver and teaching me something new! :)

Greeting,

Lina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Excel version I have at work is in Spanish. However, I think in English something like

```
=IF(EXACT(A1, "Medication A"), A1, 0)
```

should work. You can then drag that formula down. Also, if you want no text to appear instead of a 0 in column B, you can replace 0 with "". Finally, right next to the formula bar there is a little fx sign. Click it and you can get all sorts of help regarding formulas.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(A2="medication A",A2,"")
```

it will return blank space if its not Medication A